# Upload of a new application version in Elastic Beanstalk does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

uploading new application versions to AWS Elastic Beanstalk no longer works for us.

As far as I know, there are two ways to do this:

**Option 1:**

[image]

This option has never worked for us. On the next screen, there is only a deploy button and no matter how often we click it or how long we wait, the new application version is never uploaded and deployed - very frustrating.

However, that is why we have used the second way so far: to upload a new application version first and then deploy it in the next step.

**Option 2:**

[image]

So far it has worked like this. However, when I deleted all versions, all action buttons at the top suddenly became greyed out. Especially the upload button. At first, we thought there was a hidden limit for uploads per day, but after 24 hours the button is still greyed out and we still can't upload the new application version. We also tried it in different browsers, with cleared cache, on different machines, and in incognito mode.

Best regards,

Benedikt

Comment: Update: We have now set up a new environment. Everything works perfectly here and all buttons are back and clickable. We are strongly assuming that this is a bug.

Comment: I had this issue with Option 2 when creating an environment with the sample app first. Option 1 worked for me though.